# What editor does Elliot use in Season 4 Episode 8(Mr. robot)?

Tags: editor, text-editor

sorry for the stupid question
In season 4, episode 8(Mr. Robot), Elliot writes a script. What a code editor does he use?
I will attach a pic of the environment.
Is it sublime? if is it sublime, did the font change, and indent
guide hide?
Tnx!

[A pic of the editor that he used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHYV6.jpg)

Comment: Most editors let you change the font and colors, and probably indent guides, so I don't think there's enough information to say definitively, but since the line that the cursor is on has the line number highlighted, I'm guessing its atom. https://atom.io/packages/structure-view

Answer (score 1):

It looks like not Sublime Text, because

- Python syntax. Token `__name__` is colored with 2 colors, while ST uses one Id color. And string token `"__main__"` is colored with 2 colors, while ST uses single color. It may be some custom ST syntax, though.
- Sublime shows indent-guide vertical lines, screenshot don't have them. Lines can be hidden, though.

It looks like Sublime Text because:

- function word `def` in Python has italic font. Like in ST3.
- gutter shows colored back of current line, and yellow vertical bar on the left, for changed line. Sublime does it! VS Code don't do it (by default?).